# URL redirection in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Current URL is

```
http://example.com/news/club/teamname
```

(Actual file is in this path only need to change URL)

I want to changed to

```
http://example.com/team/teamname
```

Using htaccess, its a wordpress site. I can't change the permalink.

Comment: Can you share what you tried so far?

Comment: RewriteRule ^team/(.*) news/club/$1 [L,NC,R=302]  
I tried this, working fine, but the url not redirecting.

Comment: if your first url is the one to be redirected (not the other way round), your attempt is in wrong order: `RewriteRule ^/?news/club/(.*) /team/$1 [L,NC,R=301]`

also try 301 instead of 302

Comment: Its get redirected but the original file path is news/club that can not be change. I just want change the url only. Is that possible

Comment: so you are typing `/team/teamname` but the redirection isn't happening or the url is getting redirected to some other location?